Can't do logging using serilog in the elasticsearch. due to some setting isuues
internal class ConfigLogger
{
    public ConfigLogger()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
            .WriteTo.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(ConfigureElasticSink(ConfigUtility.Configuration, ConfigUtility.CurrentEnvironment))
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", ConfigUtility.CurrentEnvironment)
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(ConfigUtility.Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
    ElasticsearchSinkOptions ConfigureElasticSink(IConfigurationRoot configuration, string environment)
    {
        return new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(ConfigUtility.GetValue("ElasticSearchConfiguration:Uri")))
        {
            AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
            IndexFormat = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name.ToLower().Replace(".", "_")}-{environment.ToLower()}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-mm}",
            BatchAction = ElasticOpType.Create,
            NumberOfReplicas = 1,
            NumberOfShards = 2,
            ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.BasicAuthentication("", ""),
        };
    }
}

This is how I am doing configuration of the serilog and creating a new logger configuration.
services.AddLogging(builder =>
 {
     builder.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true);
 });

And making a service of the logger in the service extension.
the config logger is initiated in the main function.
But the main problem is that whenever I make a log the elasticsearch terminal. But it does not make logs in the index.

[2024-04-12T09:55:15,326][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetadataIndexTemplateService] updating index template [serilog-events-template] for index patterns [neo-fleet-manager-development-2024-25]

how should I rectify this error.
appsettings.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ElasticSearchConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://localhost:9200",
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "DefaultIndex": ""
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
} 

I was simply trying to change the log level, but as I can not make changes in the serilog inner function I am not able to debug it.

why don't you put your elastic sink in to the serilog section in appsetting.json ? https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch - they have full support for  reading config from serilog section and in documentation there is Handling errror is sing fails.
